# Ignoring an required field of an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I got the following variable into my entity:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]   
[DisplayName("Value U$:")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Currency Required.")]
public decimal? CurrecyValue { get; set; }
```

Actually Im  using this entity and I dont need this field. As soon as I post any information the ModelState becomes invalid because its required.

I know that I can use `ModelState.Clear();` but, doing this I'll ignore all the other validations that I need.

Is there any way to just ignore this specific field without clearing my whole `ModelState` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why can't you just remove the RequiredAttribute?

Comment: @tvanfosson Because I use it a lot on other places. I got many similar cases like that. If I remove this attribute I'll need to got to each screen wich uses and implement a specific validation for that field.

Comment: What if you just give it a default, dummy value via a hidden field?

Comment: @tobias86 Maybe a solution, I just came here to figure out a better way to solve that. I have found the helper `ModelState.Remove`that I think that I can remove this validation. There's two overloads and the only one that I can understand nicelly is a bit dangerous because I need to specify the keynumber for that. If my entity recieve a new field in the future this key number could change and make this validation become live again.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this an entity or a view model?  If it's an entity then how can you have a view that doesn't require the property.  If it's a view model then why reuse the (entire) model for that view, why not have separate models for each view (using inheritance for common properties)?

Comment: @tvanfosson its an entity and my ViewModel use this entity. This entity has many fields (required and not required) and I use many of them (including their validation). This specific field wont be shown into the screen that Im developing so I dont need to validate it.

Comment: @Dan-SP I think the right way would be to have separate models, specific to each view.  Use composition or inheritance to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugly and totally not recommended workaround:

```
ModelState.Remove("CurrecyValue");
```

Recommended solution:

Use view models. But real view models. Not some hybrids which you call *view models* and into into which you stick your domain entities and which you wonder how to get rid of simply because they are not adapted to the requirements of the given view. You should define a specific view model for each of your views. If you don't follow this very simple rule you will struggle a lot with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: After your and Mr Tvanfosson declarations Im afraid about my view model concepts. Thanks for your help !

Comment: one of the most straight forward and best recommendations ive seen about the asp.net mvc framework.